# using SSL on Nginx or Jenkins?

Tags: ssl, nginx, jenkins

I have Jenkins running on Nginx on a virtual machine. I need to secure trafic, should I apply SSL on Nginx or Jenkins.
(Jenkins is the only service running on that machine).

Answer (score 1):

i prefer u apply SSL on Nginx to secure the server

Comment: thank you, do you recommand using for this purpose **openssl** or **let's encrypt**. any other recommandation or useful link are more than welcome !